# Small form factor PCIe card in non small factor desktop

Tags: pci-express, adapter

I have a small form factor PCIe card that I use in a non small factor desktop.
It is working fine.

**Issue:** the L-shaped metal part of the card was too small (i.e the width of the card is smaller than the width of the desktop). I could unscrew it, but the card leaves a free space next to the connector. I do mind the space, but things are unstable and the card moves a bit every time I plug/unplug a connector.

Simple solution could be to simply buy the big version of the "L-metal part". I just do not know the official name of such part and thus failing to shop for it. Things like "PCI express attachment" or "PCI express adapter" did not work

Comment: Try "pci express bracket".

Comment: high profile or standard profile pci bracket

Answer (score -1):

That's called 'long profile bracket' =)

eBay ID 182093763975

Or you could just put the blank cover back you took out on the first place.